# What is the process to train an exotic (aerial) creature to be a mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, mount

During my current campaign we came across some knights riding aerial beasts (Giant vultures and Hippogriffs).  We sack their tower (killing off all the knights/beast trainers) and found giant vultures and hippogriffs in their pens.  They have already been trained for mounting but are not friendly to us.
What needs to be done/how long will it take to have them used as mounts for us?

Please use RAW in your answers (as our DM may not agree with other DM rulings), designer comments are ok.

Comment: Are you playing a published campaign? If so, that'd be good to include, as the materials (or supplements) may have something to say on the matter.

Comment: My DM is running Princes of the Apocalypse campaign.

Comment: I do not have this module, but usually modules have instructions for DMs on how to adjudicate Developments such as this. For example, Out of the Abyss provides guidelines on how to raise baby Hook Horrors. It is possible that the module has already covered this. Have you actually asked your DM about it? The wording of the question suggests you haven't yet.

Comment: My DMs answer is posted below - I posted it as he is not a user. It's the one quoting page 187 /downtime- that was his/my DMs ruling. I wasnt sure if that was correct/there was better answers out there.

Answer (score 11):

### Let's be clear.  It's up to the DM.

Al Sun cites the "downtime activity" rules, which applies specifically to player characters.

> You can spend time between adventures learning a new language or training with a set of tools. Your DM might allow additional training options.

Nothing in that section refers to anyone but *you*, the player-character, receiving training.  There are no general rules regarding animal training, let alone specific rules for this particular situation.

As players, you may think it would be quite cool to have flying mounts for your characters.  However, your DM is likely focused on something more important than "cool".  His job is to provide an adventure milieu with interesting stories and exciting challenges.  Flying mounts can ruin a lot of stories and make some challenges trivial.  If your DM rules that the mounts cannot be retrained or your characters lack the saddle-skills to ride them, understand that he's simply trying to give you the best overall experience.  Frodo might have thought it cool to just ride an eagle to Mount Doom, but it would have made for a boring book.

Comment: If it matters I can already fly - Im an Aarakocra with full flying abilities. I thought a flying mount would help with speed. Also, I didnt make up the adventure, the DM did.  Im just trying to find out how it is handled.  My Dm told me the below (answer) and I wanted to see if that was correct.  And Frodo flying would have just gotten shot out of the sky or eaten by Wyverns

Answer (score 1):

The **DM currently running this campaign** has ruled the following:

This seems to be a downtime activity (see PHB P. 187), which requires training:

> You can spend time between adventures learning a new
>   language or training with a set of tools. Your DM might
>   allow additional training options.
>   First, you must find an instructor willing to teach you.
>   The DM determines how long it takes, and whether one
>   or more ability checks are required.
>   The training lasts for 250 days and costs 1 gp per day.
>   After you spend the requisite amount of time and money,
>   you learn the new language or gain proficiency with
>   the new tool.

However, as your creatures are already trained as mounts, this should shorten the number of days (from 250 days).  However how many days will be up to your DM. In addition, your DM may give skill checks (animal handling) to further speed up the time involved.

Comment: Looks like you already killed the potential instructors.